# Not Seeing Page Views in Google Analytics with Consent Mode Script

Tags: wordpress, web, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, analytics

I'm having trouble with Google Analytics tracking on my website.
Despite setting up a script for Google Analytics with Consent Mode, I'm not seeing any page views in my analytics dashboard. Here's the script I'm using:

```
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}

    // Set up Consent Mode
    gtag('consent', 'default', {
    'ad_storage': 'denied',
    'analytics_storage': 'denied'
      });
    
    // Initialize Google Analytics
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'GTM-XYZ', {
        'send_page_view': false // Set to false if you want to control when to send page view
    });

    gtag('event', 'page_view');
</script> 
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GTM-XYZ"></script>
```

The script is placed in the `<head>` section of my HTML. I've verified that my GA property ID is correct.
Despite this setup, my real-time analytics dashboard in Google Analytics doesn't show any page views.
Here's what I've checked so far:

- Script execution order seems correct
- No JavaScript errors in the browser console
- Network tab shows requests being made to `www.google-analytics.com`

I'm wondering if the issue is related to the Consent Mode settings (`'ad_storage': 'denied', 'analytics_storage': 'denied'`) or something else.

I just need to count page views, nothing more, so I don't want to waste time with Google Tag Manager or similar tools.

Any insights or suggestions on why this might be happening and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check the requirements for modelled data [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11161109?hl=en). Do you meet these requirements?

- The property collects at least 1,000 events per day with
  analytics_storage='denied' for at least 7 days.
- The property has at least 1,000 daily users sending events with
  analytics_storage='granted' for at least 7 of the previous 28 days.
- It may take more than 7 days of meeting the data threshold within
  those 28 days to train the model successfully; however it's possible
  that even the additional data won't be sufficient for Analytics to
  train the model.